# Microsoft anti-cross site scripting library v3.1 download

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-commerce-server

I'm working on a 2010 SharePoint solution [windows server 2008 r2] which required Microsoft Commerce server, Installing the commerce require some prerequisites one of those is "Microsoft anti-cross site scripting library v3.1" 
and the provided links from Microsoft are useless till now !

- The official link mentioned in the commerce server 2009 r2 installation http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=199575 but it redirects me to a support page showing this message "FIX: An update is available that enables the installation of Commerce Server 2009 R2 to work with Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library v4.2.1" and the download page for this tool responds: "Sorry, the page you requested is not available."
- The other link for download is http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=051EE83C-5CCF-48ED-8463-02F56A6BFC09&displaylang=en redirects me to "Microsoft anti-cross site scripting library v4.2" and it's useless until I've this fixing tool.

So, I'm stuck here with Microsoft loops I'm not able to got neither v3.1 which supported by commerce server 2009 r2 nor fixing tool to enable installing v4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I was in a bad need for an answer for this question and that's made me keep trying until I find an answer:

- Install the last version of Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library  which is currently v4.2.1
- Navigate to your commerce server iso / msi folder and open your setup{64/86} XML file in notepad.
- In `<PlatformComponent>` /`<Detection>` replace this line:

```html
<DetectKey Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library V3.1\{05CB5D71-49EF-01C3-6797-37BDEC25E544}"/>
```

with this one:

```html
<DetectKey Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AntiXSSLibrary"/>
```

That should skip prerequisites issue and proceed with installation.